# Is it possible to monitor the calling of camera intent in android

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am in need of monitoring the camera hardware in android phone for an application i am building. I want to get an alert every time the camera hardware is accessed. Is there any possible way for this....?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that will receive any [camera button presses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON) if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But all i want is to check that any other application is trying to access the camera. Is there any solution for this....?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Would you like to be notified each time that a piece of software calls    `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
? There are things called intent filters. You can add them to your manifest file. Take a look [link=at this part of android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving).